# How to catch an exception when opening a file with CFileDialog fails

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I need to catch an exception when the file or files I am going to open is/are being in use or opened by other processes or applications. 
I am using MFC's `CFileDialog's DoModal` to open a list of selected files. However, when I click Open after selecting a file in the Open File Dialog, a small popup dialog appears stating that the selected one is being used by another application. `DoModal` method returns only (either with success or failure code) i.e after the Open File Dialog closes. So I don't know where to insert code to check if the selected file can't be opened when the Open File Dialog is open.

```
CFileDialog fd (TRUE, NULL, _T("*.pid"), OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY);
if (fd.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    //Get selected filenames 
}
```

I would want to insert an `AfxMessageBox` call when I double click to select a file or click Open button in the OpenFileDialog windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the virtual function [CFileDialog::OnShareViolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=vs-2017#onshareviolation).

Also you can remove `OFN_SHAREAWARE` and do your own check with `CFileDialog::OnFileNameOK`